# Necesito poner the_excerpt(); en las entradas de Wordpress pero no encuentro el archivo

Tags: php, wordpress

Se me pide que encuentre el fichero que contiene este código.

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
  the_post();
  the_content();
 endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

En este código tengo que añadir `the_excerpt();` para que a parte de salir el título y el contenido salga algo más. Y este algo más lo entrare el cliente. Pero no he tocado nunca wordpress y no se que archivo tengo que tocar.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @Mariano, lo tendré en cuenta en futuras ediciones.

Answer (score 0):

Los Extractos de Wordpress `excerpt` son resúmenes opcionales o descripciones de un artículo; simplemente un resúmen del artículo.

Los Extractos tienen dos usos principales:

1. Reemplazar el contenido completo en los feeds RSS cuando la opción de mostrar resúmenes es seleccionada en Escritorio > Opciones > Lectura.
2. Dependiendo del tema de WordPress, puede ser mostrado en lugares donde resúmenes rápidos sean preferibles antes que el contenido completo:

   - Resultados de búsquedas
   - Archivos de etiquetas
   - Archivos de categorías
   - Archivos mensuales
   - Archivos de autor

### Presentar los extractos de Wordpress

Para presentar los extractos de Wordpress dentro del [Loop (bucle)](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) sólo basta con llamar a la función [`the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) dentro del bucle while, de la misma manera que llamas las demás funciones, pues `the_excerpt()` es una función como las otras que tienes allí: `the_post();` o  `the_content();`

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
      the_excerpt();
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Para más información, puedes consultar [Codex de Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt)

Comment: Si lo entiendo, y se donde tengo que poner the_excerpt();. Lo que no se en que archivo esta ese codigo. No lo encuentro. Gracias

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que pretendes. ¿Podrías explicar mejor? La función se encuentra en este archivo: wp-includes/post-template.php Pero no toques al archivo, puedes dañar tu instalación de Wordpress. ¿O lo que quieres es que cuando se crea un nuevo post se muestre la parte donde se escribe el excerpt?

Comment: tienes un correo electronocio o algo para comunicarme mejor contigo?

Comment: si exacto cuando creo un post abajo que pone en expañol Extracto que es the expert, que cuando yo escriba ahi salga en la web. Entonces me han dicho que es poniendo the expert en ese trozo de codigo que tu me dices que esta en este documento wp-includes/post-template.php, no? Sino como lo hago?

Comment: @Laura Ahhh, para eso tienes que modificar la plantilla, poniendo en ella lo que se llama un _hook_ que muestre el excerpt. Eso se puede hacer de varias maneras dependiendo de si tienes Wordpress solamente o de si tienes una framework como Thesis o Genesis y también de si es un sitio con dominio propio (Wordpress.org) o un sitio sin dominio propio alojado en Wordpress.com

Comment: @Laura Eso se hace modificando el child theme, (tema hijo), no el tema en sí. Puedes ver esto: https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Temas_hijos

Comment: No es necesario meterse a estudiar temas hijos @A.Cedano, vas a enredarla todavía más. Primero dejemos que encuentre dónde hacer la modificación en el theme actual y luego se creará otra pregunta para aclarar los child themes. Su caso de uso parece ser un Wordpress autogestionado con un theme hecho a la medida para su cliente.

Comment: @amenadiel No se recomienda modificar nunca el tema padre por las razones que imagino conoces. Si tiene un framework, o aunque no lo tenga, tampoco es tan complicado modificar el tema hijo. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que lo más común es descargarse un theme de la enorme biblioteca que hay, y luego hacerse un tema hijo para hacer las modificaciones pertinentes para tus gustos. Luego cuando el theme se actualice (porque se van liberando nuevas versiones) puedes descargar la nueva sin perder tus cambios. Ese es el quid del asunto. **Para themes hechos desde cero, en realidad no tienes de qué heredar**. Pero tienes razón: una vez que el theme que se hizo desde cero está terminado, modificaciones posteriores en él sí debieran hacerse creándole temas hijos.

Comment: Lo de los temas hijos no es tan complicado como parece @amenadiel Y es la forma correcta de empezar, si queremos ahorrarnos muchos dolores de cabeza más adelante. Además la información existe en español, para mayor facilidad. Aunque esté usando uno de los temas que trae WP, si se modifica directamente el tema, aparte de que puede haber fallos en el sitio si se comenten errores en la modificación, los cambios se perderían cuando haya actualizaciones del tema.

Comment: @A.Cedano en eso estamos de acuerdo. Mi observación sólo apuntaba a los temas creados de cero a pedido del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Esa función se invoca desde las plantillas del theme de wordpress que estés usando, y dependiendo del theme, corresponderá agregarlo en ciertos lugares  y no en otros.

Esto significa que:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    if (have_posts()) :
       while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
     endwhile;
    endif;
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

Así tal cual como lo presentas, *podría no estar literal en ninguna de las plantillas de tu theme*. Lo único que sí vas a encontrar en ellas, sea el theme que sea, es el uso de `the_content();`. Y eso es lo que quieres modificar. El envoltorio que estás intentando seguir probablemente era para otro theme.

Dentro de tu theme, hay plantillas (por ejemplo `single.php` y `page.php`  en donde no tiene sentido presentar el `excerpt`), mientras que en otras, que hoy despliegan el post completo, **lo que tú quieres es, a cambio, desplegar sólo una intro más un enlace que diga : "Leer más".**

**En resumen**: dentro del theme que estés usando, **debes buscar cuales plantillas utilizan "the_content();"**

Como dije antes, hay plantillas en donde no corresponde hacer se cambio ( `single.php` y `page.php` si es que tu theme los tiene), y otros que no imprimen posts, como `functions.php`. Algunos candidatos, dentro de tu theme, pueden llamarse:

- index.php
- category.php
- tag.php
- loop.php

**Por ningún motivo** te vayas a meter a modificar `wp-includes/post-template.php`. Esto que quieres hacer debe hacerse **estríctamente** en tu theme.

Si quieres más ayuda, complementa tu pregunta listando los archivos que hay dentro de la carpeta de tu theme actual.